# Looking for SQL function that removes part of a string based on a string value in a corresponding column

Tags: sql, string, sql-update

[image]

I have a very long list of street names with intersection information. I am trying to remove "STNAME" from `From` and `To` columns in SQL.

Example table:

```
STNAME         From                   To
-----------------------------------------------------------
MAIN ST        MAIN ST & 21ST ST      22ND ST & MAIN ST
MARKET ST      58TH ST & MARKET ST    MARKET ST & 59TH ST
```

Result needed:

```
STNAME         From         To
--------------------------------------------
MAIN ST        21ST ST      22ND ST
MARKET ST      58TH ST      59TH ST
```

I have researched replace and case queries but I'm not finding what I need. I feel comfortable removing the &, but I cannot figure out how to tell it to look up the value in `STNAME` and remove it from from `From` and `To` columns.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  And what happens if the name is not in the `from` or `to`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `replace()` function within an update statement like :

```
update tab
   set from = replace(replace(from,stname,''),' & ',''),
       to = replace(replace(to,stname,''),' & ','')
```

Comment: Incredible! I am new to sql, so this has made my day! Thanks!

Comment: you're welcome @MaryEllenMcCarty. Seems it helped, kindly please accept the amswer.